# Add Pagination, sorting and filtering to Native Query

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on an application that uses materialized views and SQL queries stored in a database that are retrieved and executed using Spring's JdbcTemplate.

I'm being requested to add sorting, pagination and filtering to this application.

Since the queries are stored in the database and not persistent entities I'm a little lost on how to add this feature. I've used Spring's JPA Repository for this before with actual persistent entities and also have used hibernate criteria in the past.

The main reason for these queries being stored in the database is that this application can be deployed to different clients and they may have different materialized views and queries. They wanted to be able to use the same application (different instance) without code changes to add new views and queries.

Any help and ideas greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Will the query names always be the same? If yes, you could write NamedNativeQueries, referring to the database query names.

Comment: I may be missing your advice. The queries are stored in the database and retrieved from there. My thoughts at the moment are to use result set metadata to either parse the stored SQL and add additional where clause and limits or wrap it in a sub query... neither of which I like.

The other option, which would change our architecture, is to make a dependency project per instance with the entities specific to each client. This would allow me to utilize Spring's JPA, specifically the paging and sorting.

Comment: I might not understand your question properly - what database system do you use and how is the SQL query stored? How would you usually call or execute that query if you use an SQL client? JPA can do anything you can do in an SQL client, you only have to find the right way. You can then wrap the resultset in a bean, if needed, and I believe you could add sorting, pagination and all that too. I just wonder how you plan to make it generic, if the fieldnames aren't the same it won't work, unless you keep it in plain SQL, without a bean.